# Flutter keeps importing old version of Plugin for iOS

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, cocoapods

I have create a plugin which can be found at following url https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/upetch_paysquare_service#-versions-tab-

I imported the plugin in separate flutter project's pubspec as follows

```
upetch_paysquare_service: ^0.0.7
```

The Android part works fine. when I open the project in Xcode to run on iOS device, I get error saying `could not find file included pods..`

So I decide to update my pods
I went to terminal I keep getting error saying I did not specified any swift version in my plugin but I have specified swift version in my plugin project's pod file as follows

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'  # required
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

My main question is whenever I do `pod update` or `pod install`, the version of plugin getting installed is 0.0.2 but I am importing version 0.0.7 in my `pubspec.yaml` file.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Examine the Podfile.lock file to see the reasons pod versions are chosen.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien for my plugin project or for the project which uses the plugin dependency in pubspec.yaml file??

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I am not able to find any POdfile.lock,did you mean pub spec.lock file??

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I checked the pubspec.lock file and is it importing the version 0.0.7 which is correct, but I don't understand why iOS imports wrong version

Comment: I am getting this too and I need to know why...

Comment: @MarcosBoaventura I have no idea why this is happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case I take a look in plugin source on github and a see that you aren't updating the version of your plugin in your [`upetch_paysquare_service.podspec`](https://github.com/pritish12/upetch_paysquare_service/blob/master/ios/upetch_paysquare_service.podspec) file.

This is your current version:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'upetch_paysquare_service'
  s.version          = '0.0.2'#I Think you should update this field with '0.0.7'
  s.summary          = 'A Flutter plugin for RazorPay SDK'
s.description = <<-DESC
```

Try update in your plugin to:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
      s.name             = 'upetch_paysquare_service'
      s.version          = '0.0.7' #New Version 
      s.summary          = 'A Flutter plugin for RazorPay SDK'
    s.description = <<-DESC
```

This change can help the apps that are using your plugin get the current version when the developer run `pod install or pod update`.

Why am I telling this?

Well, I had a problem like yours a few days ago but in a different case. In my case was in an app that I am developing and all plugins and versions are working pretty fine on android side but when I start on iOS platform the things was not pretty well.
On iOS side all the plugins are coming with different versions that I declared in pubspec file, mostly in '0.0.1' version, and I was able to workaround this updating the `specific_plugin.podspec` file of each one. I really don't know if this is the correct way to solve this problem but in my case it's working!

But one exception! In my case the [geolocator plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) was the only one that are coming with correct version declared in pubspec file and I see that in his [geolocator.podspec file](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/blob/develop/ios/geolocator.podspec) the current version was updated in `s.version` property. I suppose that `pod update or pod install` read this field to download the right plugin version.

Comment: Will give a try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try `pod update upetch_paysquare_service`
then `pod install`